# Data structure used to implement recursion

Tags: data-structures

Which data structure can be used to "eliminate" recursion from a recursive program? Array, stack, queue, or list? How is it used to that end?

When I eliminate recursion from the program computing factorial $n! = n(n-1)!$, I replace recursion with a loop. But I don't see how to do a similar transformation in general.

Comment: This is because the factorial program is a very easy to implement without a recursive algorithm, therefore no need for a special data structure. But still, you need one of those data structures if you want to apply the recursive algorithm (i.e. to simulate the recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Let me restate your question: Which data structure does the CPU use to implement recursion? This data structure is knows as the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). As you can imagine, it's a stack. I strongly suggest that you consult the Wikipedia page (or any other source) and try to understand *why* a stack is used and *how* it works. This is much more important than answering a multiple-choice question.